# Abstract class as TItem in another class

Tags: c#, abstract

The following statement returns an error:

```
public class MySortedList<TKey, TItem> where TKey : struct, TItem : MyBaseClass<TKey>
```

MyBaseClass is defined as follows:

```
public class MyBaseClass<T> where T : struct
```

The error is on the second ":" after TItem - "{ expected"
What is the right syntax for this?
Thank You.

Comment: What may that error be, pray tell?

Comment: The error is on the second ":" - { expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multiple `where` keywords rather than separating the constraints on different types with a comma:

```
public class MyBaseClass<T> where T : struct{}
public class MySortedList<TKey, TItem> 
    where TKey : struct
    where TItem : MyBaseClass<TKey>
{}
```